# My |DataDirectory| points to C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE

Tags: sql, wpf, datadirectory

When I try to put |DataDirectory| into a Connection String it would keep directing to C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE for some reason. Any idea what could have altered the directory path, or where could I find the default setting for DataDirectory? App.config doesn't have a "connectionStrings" in it's code either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if you can change it in the `App.config`, but you can change the `DataDirectory` path in your c# code. In my case, we do this in the `bootstrapper`, depending on Debug/Release Configuration. You can set the `DataDirectory` with this code:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("DataDirectory", dataDirectoryPath);
```

Comment: Where can I find the bootstrapper?

Comment: sorry, this was just an example. We use the prism library, and there you can use the bootstrapper to initialize your shell. Refer to this documentation for more information: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg430868(v=pandp.40).aspx But you can do this anywehre in your code. For example you could add this to your main method or in the app.xaml.cs class.

Comment: I've already looked through every .cs file in my Solution Explorer and there's nothing in there that includes a AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData

Comment: What do you mean by include? If you did not put it in these files, then there won't be any implementation of this. This is a environmental variable which is set to a default value if you don't change it.

Comment: What I mean is that there is no AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("DataDirectory", dataDirectoryPath); or anything similar to that within all of my .cs files in my project. The default value itself might be the cause, but I don't know how to access it.

Comment: Like I said, this is nowhere in your files if you don't set it. You have to add it, if you want to change the default DataDirectory path which is set by the framework without adding it in your code. You can change this default value by adding the snippet above with any path you like.